# Filter a specific record from xml file to gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, datagridview

I have a xml file that contains data of employees. The design of my page is such that, when a user enters his ID the gridview displays his skills (if already exists) else nothing and proceeds to enter his data (new employee). I want to filter the record the data of employee using his ID and display in grid view.But upon using my code it throws exception stating "'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'EmployeeID'". I have already bounded the templates with correct values. What seems to be the problem then?

my xml schema

```
-<SkillSet>


-<SkillSets>

<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>

<EmployeeName>abc</EmployeeName>

<PLName>xyz</PLName>

<SkillName1>Html</SkillName1>

<SkillType1>Programming</SkillType1>

<SkillProficiency1>Beginner</SkillProficiency1>

<Experience1>1</Experience1>

<Comments>Hello</Comments>

</SkillSets>

</SkillSet>
```

My aspx page source code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdxml" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White"
                        BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" GridLines="Vertical"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdxml_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        onrowdeleting="grdxml_RowDeleting">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeID")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblEmpName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PL Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPLName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PLName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Skill Name 1">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSkillName1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SkillName1")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Skill Type 1">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSkillType1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SkillType1")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Skill Proficiency 1">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblSkillProf1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SkillProficiency1")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Experience">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblExp1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Experience1")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Command"> <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton Text="Select" ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" CommandName="Select" />
                                     <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>                     
                    </asp:GridView>
```

My c# code for binding grid:

```
private void BindGrid()
    {

        string filename = Server.MapPath("~/SkillSet.xml");

        if (File.Exists(filename) == true)
        {
            try
            {

                string filePath = Server.MapPath("SkillSet.xml");
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.ReadXml(filePath);
                var skillSets = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
                var query = from SkillSets in skillSets
                            where SkillSets.Field<string>("EmployeeID") == emplid
                            select SkillSets;
                grdxml.DataSource = query.ToList();
                grdxml.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblerror.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'EmployeeID'. at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName) at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts) at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String expression) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.Eval(String expression) at ASP.default_aspx.__DataBinding__control130(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\SkillSet\Default.aspx:line 230 at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren() at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding) at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) at System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() at _Default.BindGrid() in c:\Users\SkillSet\Default.aspx.cs:line 366
```

Comment: What is `emplid`?

Comment: emplid is a local variable which stores data from textbox where employee enters his ID

Comment: @panman what are you getting in `query` ?

Comment: @AfnanAhmad the query is supposed to display the record whose EmployeeID attribute matches with the one entered by user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this and its working fine:

```
var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("YourFileName.xml"));
var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
var result = str.Elements("SkillSets").Where(x => x.Element("EmployeeID").Value.Equals(emplid.ToString())).ToList();    
List<Employee> mapList = new List<Employee>();
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Employee obj = new Employee();
    obj.EmployeeID = item.Element("EmployeeID").Value;
    obj.EmployeeName = item.Element("EmployeeName").Value;
    obj.PLName = item.Element("PLName").Value;
    obj.SkillName1 = item.Element("SkillName1").Value;
    obj.SkillType1 = item.Element("SkillType1").Value;
    obj.SkillProficiency1 = item.Element("SkillProficiency1").Value;
    obj.Experience1 = item.Element("Experience1").Value;
    obj.Comments = item.Element("Comments").Value;
    mapList.Add(obj);
}

grdxml.DataSource = mapList;
grdxml.DataBind();
```

And you can create class of an `Employee` :

```
public class Employee
    {
    private string _EmployeeID;
    public string EmployeeID
    {
        get
        {
            return _EmployeeID;
        }
        set
        {
            _EmployeeID = value;
        }

    }
    private string _EmployeeName;
    public string EmployeeName
    {
        get
        {
            return _EmployeeName;
        }
        set
        {
            _EmployeeName = value;
        }
    }
    private string _PLName;
    public string PLName
    {
        get
        {
            return _PLName;
        }
        set
        {
            _PLName = value;
        }
    }

    private string _SkillName1;
    public string SkillName1
    {
        get
        {
            return _SkillName1;
        }
        set
        {
            _SkillName1 = value;
        }
    }

    private string _SkillType1;
    public string SkillType1
    {
        get
        {
            return _SkillType1;
        }
        set
        {
            _SkillType1 = value;
        }
    }

    private string _SkillProficiency1;
    public string SkillProficiency1
    {
        get
        {
            return _SkillProficiency1;
        }
        set
        {
            _SkillProficiency1 = value;
        }
    }

    private string _Experience1;
    public string Experience1
    {
        get
        {
            return _Experience1;
        }
        set
        {
            _Experience1 = value;
        }
    }

    private string _Comments;
    public string Comments
    {
        get
        {
            return _Comments;
        }
        set
        {
            _Comments = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try implementing it and update the results :)

Comment: I used it and got it to work..Thanks so much for your help sir.